# OSQL command in batch, how to insert multiple chunks into a record

Tags: sql, batch-file, osql

Im using OSQL (SQL Server 2000) and have a batch file that chunks up an html source into 8xxx bytes of data. how can i get the chunks back into  an sql record? here are the details:

batch file for osql statement:

```
    echo use database;>tempsql.sql
    echo set indentity_insert tablename ON;>>tempsql.sql
    echo insert into tablename (ID, Name, Date, Body_HTML)>>tempsql.sql
    echo values ('%id%', '%name%', '%cdate%', '%body_html%');>>tempsql.sql
    echo set indentity_insert tablename OFF;>>tempsql.sql
    echo go>>tempsql.sql
    osql -U user -P pass -d database < tempsql.sql -o sqloutput.rpt
```

all of the variables BUT %Body_Html% fit in the 8k stack, but the data for %body_html% is larger than 8k (up to 50k) so it has to be "chunked" down to fit in the stack. below is just part of the chunk routine for you to review (many thanks to jeb and dbenham for this):

```
    @echo off
    set count=0
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("newhtml.htm") do set FileSize=%%~za
    echo FileSize is %FileSize% bytes
    if %FileSize% GTR 8159 goto split
    rem skip regular insert routine, pick up at :split
    :split
        set count=0
set /a all_sub=%FileSize% / 8159
set /a all_rem=%FileSize% %% 8159
if %all_rem% NEQ 0 set /a all_ttl=%all_sub% + 1
echo %all_sub% full page(s), %all_rem% bytes(s) leftover, %all_ttl% total pages
chunk newhtml.htm basenam -s8159 -o
set count=0
     :: now get accurate file count of basenam.*
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir basenam.* ^| find "File"') do (
    set setfiles=%%a
)
echo  %setfiles%>setfiles
set count=0
     ::now show where the break is
     echo Loop %count%
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion 
set "all="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ basenam.00%count%"`) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:#=#S!"
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    for /F "delims=" %%p in ("!all!#L!line!") do (
        ENDLOCAL
        set "all=%%p"
    )
)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined all (
set "all=!all:~2!"
set ^"all=!all:#L=^

!"
set "all=!all:#S=#!")
:: now display file in 8159 byte chunks, does emit a blank line in between
echo !all!
set /a count=!count! + 1
for /f "tokens=*" %%m in (setfiles) do set setfiles=%%m
if %count% EQU !setfiles! goto end
goto loop1
:end
```

so how can i merge my chunk routine with my osql routine? i know that i will probably have to nest some FOR loops, but cant think of a way to do this based on above parameters.

and Chunk, can be found here: http://www.oldskool.org/pc/chunk

**edit:** so it would seem that maybe i need to think the logic a different way
in the osql loop, how could i 1) read mulitple variables or 2) read a file, as variable %body_html% into the oqsl results file (sqloutput.rpt)

should i break up the echo statements like this:

```
    echo use database;>tempsql.sql
    echo set indentity_insert tablename ON;>>tempsql.sql
    echo insert into tablename (ID, Name, Date, Body_HTML)>>tempsql.sql
    echo values ('%id%', '%name%', '%cdate%', '>>tempsql.sql
    rem  %body_html%
    rem put chunk routine here
    rem echo !All!>>tempsql.sql
    echo ';>>tempsql.sql
    echo set indentity_insert tablename OFF;>>tempsql.sql
    echo go>>tempsql.sql
```

now i think that might work, though it is not pretty. will post my results later.

Comment: maybe do this:     echo use database;>tempsql.sql     echo set indentity_insert tablename ON;>>tempsql.sql     echo insert into tablename (ID, Name, Date, Body_HTML)>>tempsql.sql     echo values ('%id%', '%name%', '%cdate%', '%body_html%');>>tempsql.sql     echo set indentity_insert tablename OFF;>>tempsql.sql     echo go>>tempsql.sql     osql -U user -P pass -d database < tempsql.sql -o sqloutput.rpt

Comment: tried to format above, no luck

Answer (score 0):

so this inded (the logic) worked as far as generating the sql file with the entire html inserted into the tempsql file. if anyone is interested, i will post the code.